# Equivalent of yum distro-sync?

Tags: package-management, apt, aptitude

In redhat-based distros, the yum tool has a distro-sync command which will synchronize packages to the current repositories.  This command is useful for returning to a base state if base packages have been modified from an outside source.  The docs for the command is:

> **distribution-synchronization or distro-sync** 
>   Synchronizes the installed package set with the latest packages available, this is done
>   by either obsoleting, upgrading or downgrading as appropriate. This
>   will "normally" do the same thing as the upgrade command however if
>   you have the package FOO installed at version 4, and the latest
>   available is only version 3, then this command will downgrade FOO to
>   version 3.

Is there an equivalent operation in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do this by a adding a **/etc/apt/preferences**
profile that pinned all packages to the distro/release that
repo represents. The next time you run apt-get upgrade it
will downgrade as necessary to satisfy the rules specified.
See **man apt_preferences** for details.

http://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences

The flip side of this is to prevent this from occurring to
begin with by pinning the packages you have a stake in
staying stable. So if they're updated by an *outside source*,
the next apt-get upgrade will revert just that and not your
entire OS.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that out.  The use case that brought this up was  that I installed the Unity 5.0 PPA in Precise.  When 5.0 was added to precise, I wanted to track the percise repo and remove the PPA.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such command in the apt package system, for what I know.

The `dist-upgrade` command of `apt-get` is similar, but it do not downgrade packages. The `install` command could downgrade a package as in

```
sudo apt-get install "package"="version"
```

but as you see you should explicitly give the desired version number, which you can retrieve from

```
apt-cache policy "package"
```

Comment: Yes, `dist-upgrade` _does_ downgrade packages. Otherwise this is correct.